# Unable to add Time Attribute to Network Dataset in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, drive-time-areas

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.

I want to setup service areas but I'm unable to use the time attribute. I want to use the cutoff in minutes to create service areas but the units for time say it's unavailable.

I have a network dataset. I have 'Time' as part of my attribute table. I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Can you add more info, it is unclear what you mean by "but I'm unable to use the time attribute" and "but the units for time say it's unavailable".

Comment: I want to find out which are the closest areas to my stores. I have setup a service area using network analyst. I then tried to set the layer properties. I went to Travel Mode>Costs. For the Impedence 'Time', the units are not showing up. I want to use time in minutes. In my attribute table of the Network Dataset, Time is a column. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is anything listed where the units should be?  You could look at the tutorial data and see how\if your data differs https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d6bd91b2fddc483b8ccbc66942db84cb

Comment: It says 'unspecified units'. I will take a look at the tutorial data and compare. Thank you.